# NodeJS - Error installing with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>npm install caress-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/caress-server
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/caress-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jspack/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffertools
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jspack/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffertools

> buffertools@2.0.1 install C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\caress-server\node_
modules\buffertools
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\caress-server\node_modules\buffertools>node "G:
\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-
gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (G:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:101:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at G:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\confi
gure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "G:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\caress-server\node_modules\buffert
ools
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! buffertools@2.0.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the buffertools@2.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the buffertools package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls buffertools
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "G:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "G:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "install" "caress-server"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Windows\system32>
```

I am installing a certain NodeJS script - [Caress](http://caressjs.com/). But i am not unable to. I am using Windows 8.1, can anyone tell me what is the problem i am facing, and why is this installation not working. There seems to be a problem with the buffertools dependency, thats far as i can think. Dont know how maybe fix this?

If i download the build from github and place it in node-modules, nothing seems to work. when i try to start, using npm start, or during implementation either.

```
G:\nodejs\node_modules\caress-server>npm install

G:\nodejs\node_modules\caress-server>npm start

> caress-server@0.1.1 start G:\nodejs\node_modules\caress-server
> node examples/server.js

   info  - socket.io started

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/buffertools.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\nodejs\node_modules\caress-server\node_modules\buf
fertools\buffertools.js:16:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

npm ERR! caress-server@0.1.1 start: `node examples/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the caress-server@0.1.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the caress-server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node examples/server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls caress-server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "G:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "G:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd G:\nodejs\node_modules\caress-server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     G:\nodejs\node_modules\caress-server\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

G:\nodejs\node_modules\caress-server>
```

Comment: the env variable wasnt set. dsnt work with that either.
http://pastebin.com/jBXwi63a

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Python on Windows for Node.js dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies)

Answer (score 387, accepted):

##### As commented below you may not need to install VS on windows, check this out

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245

#### UPDATED 02/2016

Some npm plugins need **`node-gyp`** to be installed.

However, **`node-gyp`** has its own dependencies ([from the github page](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp)):

[image]

#### UPDATED 09/2016

If you're using Windows you can now install all `node-gyp` dependencies with single command (NOTE: Run As Admin in Windows PowerShell):

```
 $ npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

and then install the package

```
 $ npm install --global node-gyp
```

#### UPDATED 06/2018

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809#issuecomment-155019383

> Delete your $HOME/.node-gyp directory and try again.

See full documentation here: [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

Comment: So when i install it on a linux box. What do i do in place of ms vc++?

And i get this when i did all the things u mentioned. - http://pastebin.com/LgJEKFFS

Comment: A proper C/C++ compiler toolchain, like GCC: `sudo apt-get install g++`

Comment: @Spock To be honest, using windows server is crazy IMHO, what's wrong with linux?

Comment: @IlanFrumer oh I'd prefer Linux any time, but sometimes I have to install applications on a customer's server..

Comment: @Spock as for python, I think you can use a portable version somehow , but as of VC++,  well you must have a compiler don't you?!

Comment: I ended up using Winser.. npm install winser

Comment: @Spock could you please tell how to use winser instead of npm-gyp if a package still have npm-gyp as dependency?

Comment: That helped. On Windows make sure that you install Python 2.7.x as mentioned, and NOT the latest version (3.4 currently). Luckily you can have them both installed at the same time :).
ALSO I had to add the '--msvs_version=2013' switch when installing Protractor. That's because I don't have Visual Studio 2010 but am running Visual Studio 2013 (Community edition). So use.:
npm install -g protractor --msvs_version=2013

Comment: Wouldn't this be solved by having a not-VS-dependent C++ compiler installed on Windows? Is such a thing impossible to find? I'm confused.

Comment: This worked great! I'm adding keywords in here for better visibility for AngularJS developers needing to set up Karma test runner and running into issues. Also helpful was the following: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/preparing-to-use-karma-test-runner.html

Comment: I wanted to install ngBoilerplate and start a new app. but I had errors. so I thought old copy of windows. reinstall windows. clean copy. yey, npm -g install grunt-cli karma bower? nonono...because...same errors!!! then came to this post, and start doing c*ap...install python, install VS, install node-gyp...wow, the whole screen got red, other errors! so probably the vs 2012 was too old? I am now installing 2013 (didn't uninstall 2012, too many things in add/remove - so long to my clean install)....WHY??? I wanted to give up VS and try sublime text 3. Is it really not possible to escape??

Comment: @IlanFrumer does **Windows 10** meet same criteria and needs **VS** to be installed or not? I assume it same as for **Windows 8**, but to be sure.

Comment: The info about VS is **outdated**. You do not need VS anymore, as  [mousetraps expains on GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245). Microsoft now provides a prepackaged [Visual C++ Build Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49983). So you only need to install python plus the MS Build Tools. Just follow mousetrap's 4-step-instruction in the link above and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for support guys, works for me. Just a tip: run as admin in windows

Comment: Can you pretty please include the text in your answer for windows that an "Admin Powershell required!"

Comment: How much time will it take after running this command                                     `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Comment: @AshishChoudhary In my case it took roughly 8min (Win10/i7)

Answer (score 17):

NOTE: This is an old answer that applied to earlier versions of NodeJS.  My sincere gratitude to these open source projects that responded to this issue and resolved this former pain.

Make sure you have all the required software to run `node-gyp`:

- https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

You can configure version of Visual Studio used by `node-gyp` via an environment variable so you can avoid having to set the `--msvs_version=2012` property every time you do an npm install.

Examples:

- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2012` for Visual Studio 2012
- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013e` (the 'e' stands for FREE 'express edition')

For the full list see

- https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.29/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py#L209-294

This is still painful for Windows users of NodeJS as it assumes you have a copy of Visual Studio installed and many end users will never have this. So I'm lobbying Joyent to the encourage them to include web sockets as part of CORE node and also to possible ship a GNU gcc compiler as part of NodeJS install so we can permanently fix this problem.

Feel free to add your vote at:

- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8005#issuecomment-50545326

Comment: I just (finally) had it working with VS 2015 Community edition.  I'm on Window 10, 64 bits.  I used "npm  config set msvs_version 2015 -g" in command prompt (after installation of VS, of course).  Most people falling on this problem over time have suggested VS2010, or sometimes up to 2013, but I solved at least my current node-gyp problem with VS2015.  I had to "npm install -g sigmund" and manually install "lru-cache" from Github, also.  Original problem was to have "Utf-8-Validate" installed, as a dependancy of an Aurelia sample.

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the issue with the error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error

gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

Here is what I was doing and what finally worked.

**Disclaimer**: I am just getting my hands into Node, Angular after many years in the Java, Linux world among others...

**Environment Description**: Windows 8.1 64-bit; Cygwin; cygwin bash shell

**Command used that led to error**: npm install -g karma

**Error**: 
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.

**Discovery**: 'which python' on bash shell clearly shows '/usr/bin/python'. Now that is annoying!

**Solution**: This is only applicable to those using the environment similar to what I have, i.e. using cygwin and bash shell. Hope it helps in other environments as well but keep in mind that your kettle of tea may look a little different than mine.

1. Firstly, need to set the $PYTHON shell env variable in .bashrc using the explicit windows path to the python executable and not the unix like root path (/usr/bin) used by cygwin.
2. Secondly, and this one took a lot of trial/error and here's the gotcha! Cygwin installs python under /usr/bin (which is really a mirror of /bin on windows) with the version, i.e. (in my system) /usr/bin/python2.7.exe and then adds a link /usr/bin/python --> python2.7.exe. The problem is that gyp cannot follow this link and keeps giving the annoying error that it cannot find python even though you can find it just fine from the shell command line.
3. With the above background now add the following line to your .bashrc

export PYTHON="C:/cygwin64/bin/python2.7.exe (or whatever is the version on your system)"

4. Now source your .bashrc from your home directory (on cygwin)--> 'source .bashrc'

You should be fine now and gyp will find the python executable.

I hope this helps someone stumbling on the same or similar issue.

Comment: This is what solved my problem using GitBash 2.6.3 on Windows

Answer (score 3):

should be able get all node-gyp dependencies with [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org) for Windows

```
choco install python2
choco install visualstudioexpress2013windowsdesktop
```

Answer (score 2):

## Setup JavaScript Environment

### 1. Install Node.js

Download installer at NodeJs website. You can download the latest V6

### 2. Update Npm

Npm is installed together with Node.js. So don't worry.

### 3. Install Anaconda

Anaconda is the leading open data science platform powered by Python. The open source version of Anaconda is a high performance distribution of Python. It can help you to manage your python dependency. You can use it to create different python environment in the futher if you want to touch with it.

> Node-gyp only support >= Python 2.7 and < Python 3.0
>
> So just install the 2.7 version

### 4. Install Node-gyp

You can install with `npm`:

`$ npm install -g node-gyp`

You will also need to install:

- On Windows:

  - Option 1: Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator).
  - Option 2: Install tools and configuration manually:
  - Visual C++ Build Environment:

    - Option 1: Install [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) using the **Default Install** option.
    - Option 2: Install [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) (or modify an existing installation) and select *Common Tools for Visual C++* during setup. This also works with the free Community and Express for Desktop editions.

    > [Windows Vista / 7 only] requires [.NET Framework 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773)
  - Launch cmd, `npm config set msvs_version 2015`

  If the above steps didn't work for you, please visit [Microsoft's Node.js Guidelines for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules) for additional tips.

If you have multiple Python versions installed, you can identify which Python version `node-gyp` uses by setting the '--python' variable:

`$ node-gyp --python C:/Anaconda2/python.exe`

If `node-gyp` is called by way of `npm` *and* you have multiple versions of Python installed, then you can set `npm`'s 'python' config key to the appropriate value:

`$ npm config set python C:/Anaconda2/python.exe`

### Future update for Node.js and npm

Download installer from their official website and direct install it. The installer will automatic help you to remove old files.

`npm update npm`

### Future update for Python

`conda update --all`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with downgrading Node from  v12.8.1 to v11.15.0 and everything installed successfully

Answer (score 1):

> gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python
>   executable "python", you can set the PYT HON env variable.

This means the Python env. variable should point to the executable python file, in my case:
`SET PYTHON=C:\work\_env\Python27\python.exe`

Answer (score 1):

#### For Cygwin users:

The python issue with using `npm` on an out-of-the-box Cygwin installation, is that `node-gyp` is giving a misleading [error](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/987) due to incomplete checking in the `../npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js` code.

It's due to how Cygwin treats symbolic links. It doesn't do that properly in an out-of-the box installation. So the error messages from the above code become misleading, as it complains about the `PYTHON` path and not the existence of `python.exe` (or link of) file itself.

There are (at least) 2 ways to resolve this.

1. *Installing the Cygwin package `cygutils-extra` and use `winln`.*
2. *Use native Windows CMD in Admin mode.*

---

For (**1**) you can create a proper symlink from within Cygwin shell by doing these steps:

```bash
# To make the Cygwin environment treat Windows links properly: 
# Alternatively add this to your `.bashrc` for permanent use.
export CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict

# Install Cygwin package containing "winln"
apt-cyg install cygutils-extra

# Make a proper Windows sym-link:
cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/
winln.exe -s python2.7.exe python.exe

# Add PYTHON as a native Windows system wide variable (HKLM) 
setx /M PYTHON "C:\cygwin64\bin\python"
```

(Also assuming you are running the Cygwin shell as Admin.)
Using `apt-cyg` is recommended and can be found in various forms on github.

---

For (**2**) the resolution for out-of-the-box Cygwin users is this:

```
# Open a native Windows CMD in Administrator mode and:
cd C:\cygwin64\bin\
mklink python.exe python2.7.exe
```

The result should look like this:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin>ls -al python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx            xxx   13 Jun  2  2015 python -> python2.7.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrators xxx   13 Aug 24 17:28 python.exe -> python2.7.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx            xxx   13 Jun  2  2015 python2 -> python2.7.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx            xxx 9235 Jun  2  2015 python2.7.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

**For windows**

Check python path in system variable.
npm plugins need node-gyp to be installed.

open command prompt with admin rights, and run following command.

*npm install --global --production windows-build-tools*

*npm install --global node-gyp*

Answer (score 1):

I was working on an old Vue 2.x project, at least 2 years old and deps were never updated. Reverting to Node v10.16.3 worked for me. Versions 14 and 12 did not work.

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was:

```
rm -rf  ~/.node_gyp and
sudo npm install -g node-gyp@3.4.0
cd /usr/local/lib sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.5.dylib 
brew install gcc
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I was installing appium by npm install -g appium and getting the same error on Windows 10.

Below command worked for me:

```
npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools
```

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/33

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered but these were not working in my case which is alpine Linux based OS so maybe this helps someone else.

I was also getting same error

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

So fix by single line just add this if you are working in Dockerfile or install it in OS

```
apk add --no-cache python nodejs
```

in ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

**Note: Node version:8**

Answer (score 0):

install node-gyp and c++ compiler (gcc-c++).

Comment: Can you explain how this is a better answer than the other 11 already here?

Comment: Hi Stephan, for sure its not the better one, but yeah in a minimal steps that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools