# Installing Karma failed

Tags: angularjs, npm, karma-jasmine

Tried to install Karma

```
npm install -g karma
```

A warning is produced

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.5
```

At the end it seems there is no Karma installed

```
karma init karma.config.js
'karma' is not recognized as an internal or external command (so a windows installation).
```

However there seems to be a karma in

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma
```

and a builerror.log file

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:108:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd  C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.36
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Do I need to install python in order to work with karma or is something else wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the command line interface so that `karma` will be recognised:

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

[Karma Installaltion Guide](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/intro/installation.html)

The `node-gyp` error is because python isn't installed. To avoid that error follow the following steps:

- Install python (v2.7.10 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported): http://www.python.org/getit/windows/
- Make sure that you have a PYTHON environment variable, and it is set to drive:\path\to\python.exe not to a folder
- Install Visual Studio

**Windows XP/Vista/7:**
 - Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2013 (Express version works well)
 - If the install fails, try uninstalling any C++ 2010 x64&x86
   Redistributable that you have installed first
 - If you get errors that the 64-bit compilers are not installed you may
   also need the compiler update for the Windows SDK 7.1

**Windows 7/8:**
 - Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2013 for Windows Desktop (Express version
   works well)

**Windows 10:**
 - Install Visual Studio Community 2015 Edition. (Custom Install, Select
   Visual C++ during the installation)
 - Set the environment variable GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
 - Run the command prompt as Administrator

If the above steps have not worked or you are unsure please visit http://www.serverpals.com/blog/building-using-node-gyp-with-visual-studio-express-2015-on-windows-10-pro-x64 for a full walkthrough

**All Windows Versions**
 - For 64-bit builds of node and native modules you will also need the
   Windows 7 64-bit SDK

You may need to run one of the following commands if your build complains about WindowsSDKDir not being set, and you are sure you have already installed the SDK:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\Setenv.cmd" /Release /x86
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\Setenv.cmd" /Release /x64
```

Source: [node-gyp Github](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

Comment: I still see the same issue even after installing the cli. The documentation says to do npm install karma --save-dev first anyway... still looking for a solution here.

Comment: Yes. If you install Karma but don't install the cli you will get 'karma' is not recognized as an internal or external command. If you don't do this you will need to run Karma by using `./node_modules/karma/bin/karma`. Also check your path variable on windows to make sure it includes the the npm global package path.

Comment: But answer to original question about Python error is not solved !

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It has noting to do with the question asked.

Comment: @RajV How so? The reason for `'karma' is not recognized as an internal or external command` is because `npm install -g karma-cli` wasn't run.

Comment: In this case installation of Karma had failed because of the node-gyp issue. That needs to be fixed first. In addition, as you have noted, karma-cli needs to be installed globally for the karma command to be available.

Comment: @RajV That node-gyp is a warning. You can still run karma without node-gyp installed. To install node-gyp you need to install python. Follow the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21366601/368997

Comment: In some cases the node-gyp issue completely hobbles Karma. Even after you install karma-cli if you run the karma command it fails with runtime error. I had to basically update my Node install and reinstalled karma and karma-cli. This solved the node-gyp problem. Now karma works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366601/368997.
Karma requies node-gyp, and `node-gyp` has its own dependence (from the [github](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp)).
Especially Windows, you need **python** and make sure that you have a PYTHON environment variable.