# Node install dependencies error

Tags: node.js, npm

I have

```
node -v v0.12.2
npm -v 2.7.4 

npm config get prefix
d:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Laravel5
```

I try to use npm install command and I`m getting this error

```
d:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Laravel5>npm install                       
-                                                                           
> node-sass@2.1.1 install d:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Laravel5\node_mod
> node scripts/install.js                                                   


npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601                                                
npm ERR! argv "d:\\OpenServer\\OpenServer\\domains\\Laravel5\\\\node.exe" "d
in\\npm-cli.js" "install"                                                   
npm ERR! node v0.12.2                                                       
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4                                                        
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                    

npm ERR! node-sass@2.1.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`                 
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                      
npm ERR!                                                                    
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@2.1.1 install script 'node scripts/install.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,          
npm ERR! not with npm itself.                                               
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:                    
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js                                        
npm ERR! You can get their info via:                                        
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass                                         
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.                   

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:        
npm ERR!     d:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Laravel5\npm-debug.log        

d:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Laravel5>
```

Comment: Did you read that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by this, npm config get prefix d:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Laravel5?

Please try to use this command and try it,

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

else

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score -1):

if i understand your question correctly , maybe you can clean the `npm package cache` and try again~

```
npm cache clean
```