# Error installing grunt-iconizr with NPM

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I´m using this command to install grunt-iconizr:

```
npm install grunt-iconizr
```

iconizr requires node-gyp, and this module requires Python 2.7 and Windows Visual Studio...I follow the steps described in this post: [NodeJS - Error installing with NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm)

But when I run the command I get the following gyp ERR! build error:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code:
1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp
\lib\build.js:267:23)
```

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you have [the necessary tools installed](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) for node-gyp to work?

Comment: yes, I have installed Visual Studio express 2012 and Python and works the "python" command