# Yoeman angular/meanjs generator C compilation error - Ubuntu

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, npm, yo

Trying to use Yoeman on node 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.0.4, everything vanilla just installed. Both the mean.js generator and the angular generator fail on the same error during compiling C source. Here is the relevant part of the console output:

```
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency jasmine-core@* included from karma-jasmine will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@>=0.9 included from karma-phantomjs-launcher will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency phantomjs@>=1.9 included from karma-phantomjs-launcher will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@^0.13.0 || >= 0.14.0-rc.0 included from grunt-karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN engine karma@0.13.9: wanted: {"node":">=0.10 <=0.12 || >=1 <=3"} (current: {"node":"4.0.0","npm":"2.14.2"})
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.8

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                  ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                            ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: error: call of overloaded ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’ is ambiguous
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:10:0:
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:676:61: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
                                                             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:683:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
     return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
            ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-28-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                  ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                            ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: error: call of overloaded ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’ is ambiguous
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:10:0:
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:676:61: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
                                                             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:683:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
     return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
            ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-28-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                  ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                            ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: error: call of overloaded ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’ is ambiguous
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:10:0:
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:676:61: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
                                                             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:683:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
     return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
            ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-28-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                  ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                            ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: error: call of overloaded ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’ is ambiguous
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:10:0:
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/ayman/.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:676:61: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
                                                             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:683:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
     return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
            ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-28-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0

> phantomjs@1.9.18 install /home/ayman/projects/angular-coach/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the [node-gyp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) page, it says you need

- python (v2.7 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)
- make
- A proper C/C++ compiler toolchain, like GCC

to install node-gyp properly. Double check they are installed correctly.

This question also have few suggesions: [NodeJS - Error installing with NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm)