# Aurelia skeleton sample - dist/main.js not found?

Tags: aurelia

I’m trying to run skeleton-navigation-typescript-vs on my windows machine but it fails – I see only welcome screen and in developer tools there is a message:

http://localhost:9000/dist/main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

I do everything from the docs – step by step. http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.8/doc/article/a-production-setup.

When I check in chrome developer tools in Sources tab there are only css, jspm_packages, lib and index.html – there is no dist dir.

Is this working sample? What I’m doing wrong?

Comment: do you have any errors in console when running `gulp build` or `gulp watch`?

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the `index.html` provided by the tutorial. Go to your `index.html` and replace this:

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
```

with this:

```
<body aurelia-app>
```

When you specify a value to the `aurelia-app` attribute, the framework will look for a js file to start the application. More information at http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.8/doc/article/app-configuration-and-startup

**EDIT**

Create a main.js file inside src folder, like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

Re-run gulp-watch and see what happens now.

Comment: First off all in my opinion when I’m downloading sample it should just work without changing anything. When I try again in VS it works without changing anything… this is very strange

Comment: I downloaded the sample here and it works fine without changing anything. Are you using the latest version of NodeJS? Try to update NodeJS

Comment: OK – on clean machine I’m almost there… I have only windows, chrome and fiddler and then I fallow installation of git, npm, jspm, gulp and configure newest source code release from couple hours ago. Everything worked ok this time (on other machine where I have Visual studio and other stuff the installation failed on ‘npm install’). But when I’m run page with ‘gulp watch’ and try to browse it a see only splash screen and information about connection to bowersync – and it stays this way ;(

Comment: what about the error message in the browser's console? still the same message? If yes, see my edited answer

Comment: OK I finally done this - VS has only web components and Aurelia is also using C++. I think that startup tutorial has lack of required components – python and C++ compilers (VS for example)

Comment: Well, those python errors happened with me as well. However, they make no difference, even with the errors, everything works fine for me. See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299987/aurelia-npm-install-tons-of-gyp-err perhaps it helps

Comment: `<body aurelia-app="main">` caused the problem in my case. Thanks a lot!