# nodejs Buffer toString function for UTF-32

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with a binary file that I am trying to parse through and store as variables using NodeJs.  I have the file currently in a Buffer.  This Part of the file according to the requirements document is UTF-32.

```
41 00 00 00  55 00 00 00  54 00 00 00  4F 00 00 00 
31 00 00 00  45 00 00 00  30 00 00 00  33 00 00 00 
38 00 00 00  31 00 00 00  31 00 00 00  36 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00

var string_UserName = data.toString('utf-8', 96, 179);
console.log('User Name: ' + string_UserName);
//User Name: A   U   T   O   1   E   0   3   8   1   1   6

var string_UserName = data.toString('utf-16le', 96, 179);
console.log('User Name: ' + string_UserName);
//User Name: A U T O 1 E 0 3 8 1 1 6

var string_UserName = data.toString('utf-32le', 96, 179);
console.log('User Name: ' + string_UserName);
//buffer.js:387
      throw new TypeError('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);
      ^
TypeError: Unknown encoding: utf-32le
    at Buffer.slowToString (buffer.js:387:17)
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:399:31)
```

According to the [Node Documentation for Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) there isn't something built in to convert to string utf-32.

Is there a NPM module out there that can extend BUFFER to allow this conversion or do I need to write a buffer.prototype.toString() function to extend toString(), that will allow this conversion to take place?  If so does anyone already have one they use?

---

Here is a HEX dump of the first 256/FF bytes of the file.

```
AF 03 00 00  D0 00 00 00  16 81 03 1E  0A 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
41 00 00 00  55 00 00 00  54 00 00 00  4F 00 00 00 
31 00 00 00  45 00 00 00  30 00 00 00  33 00 00 00 
38 00 00 00  31 00 00 00  31 00 00 00  36 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  32 30 31 36  30 31 32 32  31 32 33 35 
34 32 30 30  30 30 30 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
```

After using @vlad's answer

```
Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;
var convertUTF32 = new Iconv('UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
var string_UserName = convertUTF32.convert(data.slice(96, 179));
console.log('User Name: ' + string_UserName);
```

I am getting an error from ICONV:

```
C:\nodeCode\node_modules\iconv\lib\iconv.js:145
          throw errnoException('EINVAL', 'Incomplete character sequence.');
          ^

Error: Incomplete character sequence.
    at errnoException (C:\nodeCode\node_modules\iconv\lib\iconv.js:169:13)
    at Object.convert (C:\nodeCode\node_modules\iconv\lib\iconv.js:145:17)
    at Iconv.convert (C:\nodeCode\node_modules\iconv\lib\iconv.js:59:12)
    at C:\nodeCode\metaProc.js:49:37
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:404:3)
    at fs.js:312:11
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:456:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:385:13)
```

Someone suggested that it was because `data.slice(96, 179)` was not a multiple of 4 but I can't understand that since 96 if the first byte and 179 is the last byte of a 4 Byte group (176, 177, 178, 179).  180 would be the start of the next byte not the end.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Finally figured out what I was doing wrong. While @Vlad was mostly right.  I didn't have the `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` in there and had to shift the end index 1 as well since buffer.slice appears to be [Half-Closed Interval](http://www.mathwords.com/h/half_closed_interval.htm) [96, 180) and not [inclusive](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inclusive.htm) [96, 179] like I thought.

What I really needed was:

```
Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;
var iconv32 = new Iconv('UTF-32LE', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE');
var string4_UserName = iconv32.convert(data.slice(96,180)).toString('utf-8');
console.log('User Name: ' + string4_UserName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an [iconv npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv) often used for buffer decoding.

According to the its README, you can try:

```
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
var iconv = new Iconv('UTF-32LE', 'UTF-8');
var string_UserName = iconv.convert(data.slice(96, 179)).toString('utf8');
console.log('User Name: ' + string_UserName);
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: When I try to npm install iconv, it tells me I can't find Python.
> node-gyp rebuild

C:\nodeCode\node_modules\iconv>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
I was trying to find something that could be done without having to bring in a compiler.

Comment: @shaun take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21366601/2727317 
I guess you're using Windows

Comment: After modifying my copy of VS 2015 to include C++.  I finally got npm install iconv to complete.  However when I use 
`Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv; var convertUTF32 = new Iconv('UTF-32LE', 'UTF-8'); var string_UserName = convertUTF32.convert(data.slice(96, 179)); console.log('User Name: ' + string_UserName);`
All I get is an Error.
`Error: Incomplete character sequence.`
Same Error when I change it to `var string_UserName = convertUTF32.convert(data.slice(96, 179)).toString('utf8');`