# How to import Tesseract into Angular2 (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angular, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to import Tesseract into Angular2 (TypeScript). I can see it saved into the node_modules folder but when using

`import { Tesseract } from '@types/tesseract.js';`

it says:

> [ts] Module '"c:/Users/black/Projects/projectCLI/tess/node_modules/@types/tesseract.js/index"' has no exported member 'Tesseract'.

In the index.d.ts file there is a namespace called Tesseract.

Is there some other way to import this or are we looking at this the wrong way?

I used `npm install --save-dev @types/tesseract.js` to install typescript Tesseract.

If there are any demo tutorials using tesseract can you please link them here?

thanks, in advance, for your help.

Comment: `@types` just has type declarations. Do you have the actual javascript module? you have to import from there

Comment: Do you use Angular 2 with Angular CLI, Webpack or SystemJS ?

Comment: Suraj: Could you please give an example of the import syntax? It is already visible in node_modules inside @types. Thanks

_the first syntax in question is what we are trying at the moment_

Comment: @SimonaMi We use Angular 2 with AngularCLI, Webpack.

Comment: try `import * as T from Tesseract`

Comment: @Suraj this is the error we got `[ts] Cannot find module 'Tesseract'`

we also tried `import * as T from '@types/tesseract.js';` as @types... is our directory.

Comment: @suraj Just tried that and we got the following error: `gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.failNoPython (C:\Users\black\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:454:19)` (plus more)

when i ran the above command in a new project it worked perfectly. Could it be a conflict with `npm install --save-dev @types/tesseract.js` ??
Thanks

Comment: that is a different error entirely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm

Comment: @Suraj Should i make a new AngularCLI project and then try your npm install command??

Comment: no.. @types is *just* type declarations of the module..the actual module is the javascript one I put

Comment: typescript declarations are needed to import the actual javascript module in a TS project. you will need both in your project. Check the question I linked for the error

Comment: @Suraj: I started a new CLI and followed your instructions on the large error msg. First i did `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` this and then i did `npm install --global node-gyp` this installed with 0 errors. Then i ran `npm install tesseract-js --save` which gave me a really big error so i ran `npm install --save-dev @types/tesseract.js` which gave no errors.

Comment: @Suraj: `ng serve` compiles with no errors. i added `import * as T from '@types/tesseract.js';` into my app.components.ts and there are no errors. How do i use Tesseract on an image? thanks

Comment: `npm install tesseract.js --save` https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js

Comment: `npm install tesseract.js --save` worked and everything seems to be installed correctly - How do we use Tesseract methods, do we have to call new tesseract methods? im still using this `import * as T from '@types/tesseract.js';` import statement. Is it correct? cheers

Comment: import * as T from Tesseract. Let me know if it works.. will add answer

Comment: @Suraj: we used `import *as T from Tesseract` and got `[ts] String literal expected.` and then we used `import *as T from 'Tesseract'` and it gave and error `[ts] Cannot find module 'Tesseract'.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install the actual javascript module:
`npm install tesseract.js --save`

Also install @types declarations:
`npm install @types/tesseract.js --save-dev`

Finally do the folowing to import:
`import * as Tesseract from 'tesseract.js'`

To use the library check [here](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js)

The @types command saves [this type declaration file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/tesseract.js/index.d.ts).
This is a namespace and all the contents of the actual module are declared within.When you do `import * as aliasname from tessreact.js`, you can use all the functions within the namespace as `aliasname.functionname`. Example is [the test file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/tesseract.js/tesseract.js-tests.ts) for the same type declaration file.

Comment: Followed your instructions exactly, Prohram compiles with `ng serve` with zero errors an `import * as Tesseract from 'tesseract.js'` works well. 
Thanks you for this.

How do i call a Tesseract commands? we are trying 'Tesseract. ' is there another approach to this?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help - it works perfectly and we are onto actual development. :)