# How to get Tesseract to work with Angular2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, import, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use Tesseract in one my components to perform ocr on a file.

**.ts**:

```
import * as Tesseract from 'tesseract.js';

fileToUpload: File = null;
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
  }
imageOcr() {
    Tesseract.recognize(this.fileToUpload)
      .progress(message => console.log(message))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .finally(resultOrError => console.log(resultOrError));
 }
```

**.html**

```
<div>
  <h6>Local Image OCR</h6>
  <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg,.webp"  (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
  <button (click)="imageOcr()">click</button>
</div>
```

I followed  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594133/how-to-import-tesseract-into-angular2-typescript) ,
however this error shows

```
"blob:http://localhost:4200/65999042-8757-4264-b92d-ed5e0a0e4c27:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:4200/dist/worker.dev.js?nocache=qf0eq67rus' failed to load.
    at blob:http://localhost:4200/65999042-8757-4264-b92d-ed5e0a0e4c27:1:1"
```

How or what should I do to make this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594133/how-to-import-tesseract-into-angular2-typescript check this also this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract.ts

Comment: :) as stated in my post , I already checked the link you just gave me and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else encounters this , here's the solution I found : tesseract typescript wrapper.

[Here's a link to github](https://github.com/urakozz/tesseract.ts)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use another typescript wrapper dependency, when you can do it without using it also.

1. You need to install the actual javascript module:

   `npm install tesseract.js --save`
2. Also install @types declarations:

   `npm install @types/tesseract.js --save`
3. Finally do the folowing to import:

   `import * as Tesseract from 'tesseract.js'`
4. Use it like this

   `let filename = 'assets/img/abcdefg.jpg'
    Tesseract.recognize(filename)
         .progress(function (p) { console.log('progress', p) })
         .catch(err => console.error(err))
         .then(function (result) {
           console.log("result ======<<<<>>>>>");
           console.log(result.text)
     })`