# Node Js gyph errors

Tags: node.js, git, bash

Im trying to install this module with NPM install:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-adwords-es5

Somehow im getting a bunch of errors in git bash. See them here below:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\adwordsapi\node_modules\ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

It did install my package tho. Are those errors crucial for further development? I'm just starting out with nodeJS. I hope you can help me, if this has any issues for further development id like to know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have python installed?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment :(

It's a known issue with node-gyp.
Try following the thread [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/746)

Also check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm)