# Tried to install buffertools but got a MSB4102 error

Tags: node.js, msbuild

I am using **Node: 4.8.0/6.11.0**, **npm: 2.15.11** in Windows 8.1 environment.

Prerequisite:

1. I have Visual Build Tools installed (http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)
2. `set msvs_version=2015`
3. `set VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140"`

Here is the problem:
when I run **npm i buffertools**, I got a MSB4102 error

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS - Error installing with NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm)

Comment: Please check questions regarding native node modules on windows.

Comment: The problem is not related to Node or NPM version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Import path is messed up, it contains `"` in the middle of the path,  because the vcxproj likely file contains

`<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />`

and that now expands to

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140"\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.Props` because you passed quotes when setting VCTargetsPath.

Are you sure you need to set VCTargetsPath, isn't this done automatically? And in any case, if you set it, omit the quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is the quote problem.

Comment: It is because we have multiple version of MSBuildTools install. I am trying to  point it to the right one, which is vs 2015.

Comment: stijn nice one!