# ERROR An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1): Ionic Error

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/):

1.Node installed - node-v8.9.0-x86
2. ran command `npm install -g cordova ionic`

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
C:\Users\Android1\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> 
C:\Users\Android1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
C:\Users\Android1\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> 
C:\Users\Android1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 
(node_modules\ionic\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

+ cordova@7.1.0
+ ionic@3.16.0
added 115 packages and updated 2 packages in 69.815s
```

3. Then ran command `ionic start myApp tabs`  , got following  Error

[image]

Thank you,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After spending more than day i came across many solutions, which are as follow

1. Some developers solve this problem by, 
   **i downgraded node from v8 to v7.6.0 and all seems to work fine with ionic CLI.**  [From Here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2416)    but this solution not work for me.
2. **Run Command Line as Administrative**, this solution is beneficial
3. The Correct and well solution work for me, is to install  **install all node-gyp dependencies**
   by following command

   ```
    $ npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
   ```

   and then install the package

   ```
    $ npm install --global node-gyp
   ```

Solution [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm)

Comment: I had installed nodejs v10.0. After uninstalling it and installing v8.11.1 I could then proceed without any issues.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I am having macOS. can you please tell me where from i download version  8.11.1 of nodejs

Answer (score 5):

npm cache clean --force

*This command worked for me.*

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

step 1 : sudo -s

step 2 :  sudo ionic start todo blank ( for ubuntu )

Answer (score 3):

I also face the same problem.

Solution is worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04:

> sudo -s

First Get Access of Super User from Above Command

> sudo ionic start myApp tabs

After Get into SUDO Mode, then run ionic command with sudo, like above

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the simple procedure to solve this issue:

- Delete

(1)npm and

(2)npm-cache

folders manually. [You can find it in => %AppData%/npm-cache on Windows.]

- Uninstall the Node.Js application in Programs and Features in Windows-OS.
- Restart the System.
- Once again re-install Node.Js in your system, perfectly.
- open terminal anywhere (preferably from Desktop) and run

node --version

and check it is latest version.

- Run

npm --version

and check it is latest version.

- Run

git--version

and check it is latest version.

- Run

npm install -g ionic

- Finally Run,

ionic start myApp tabs

Here ==>>wait for more time (8-10 mins)<<== until all the ionic files to be downloaded, install and create a new ionic app in the given name.

- Finally, a new ionic project will be created.
- Go to the project folder of that particular ionic project and Run

ionic serve

The project will run in Browser.

All the best, Devs ..!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem. So, I installed my node module using `yarn` instead of `npm`. And it worked for me. Try it using `[Yarn][1]`

You can try it and check.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

step 1 : `sudo -s`

step 2 : `sudo ionic start todo blank` ( for ubuntu )

Answer (score 0):

Try running 'npm i' command in the project directory in sudo mode or administrator mode. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is**

** Clear npm cache

**Delete package-lock.json file from your proyect

** Access your proyect

** Run yarn install

**You may have problems with your internet conection

Answer (score 0):

I started using react instead of angular and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

My WSL machine has a problem detecting which gradlew process to run so I had to manually add '.bat' extension here:

[image]