# unable to install firebase tools in windows

Tags: windows, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

Hi I'm unable to install the firebase tools via command prompt using admin mode and I am getting the error bellow:

```
F:\rnd\MyChat>npm install  firebase

> grpc@1.8.4 install F:\rnd\MyChat\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.8.4/node-v57-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.8.4 and node@8.9.3 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\ani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.8.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.8.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies

Comment: also if you want to install globally you have to use `-g`

Comment: @SurajRao already tried those it is not working

Comment: have you installed python?

Comment: yeah 2.7 version

Comment: `python -v` works? have you set the path?

Comment: nope im setting the path in environment variables then also it is not working

Comment: restart your command prompt and see if python command is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163538/discussion-between-madpop-and-suraj-rao).

Comment: Latest version has a problem, try install previous one `npm i -g firebase-tools@v3.17.2`

Comment: i tried this 3.17.2 version but still same issue

Comment: Try npm config set python "<path_to_python_exe>" and do npm install again.

Comment: @jester Done that but still same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to install `firebase` javascript library not the `firebase-tools` the node module for firebase tools is `firebase-tools` and firebase 3.16 version and along with that in the local folder `npm install node-gyp`

you should run

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: im trying to install both firebase tools and firebase also and after entering the your command im getting these  errors  npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead & > grpc@1.8.4 install F:\rnd\MyChat\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Comment: try to run this `npm install -g node-pre-gyp` what you get ?

Comment: Installed your command below is the response im getting + node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
added 113 packages in 66.884s

Comment: npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
C:\Users\ani\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase -> C:\Users\ani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase

> grpc@1.4.1 install C:\Users\ani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.4.1/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.4.1 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI

Answer (score 0):

This is something that may work, try doing the following.

```
npm i -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally my issue has been resolved by following these below steps

firstly i installed **`npm install node-gyp`** in my local folder and downgraded my firebase-tools version from 3.17 to 3.16 and Mainly i disabled my Anti Virus
below is the reference  link for that

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/121

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of nodejs try uninstalling and using node-v10.15.3

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.15.3/