# node-sspi installation error with node V12

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

Im trying to install node-sspi, but im getting the following error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
```

Is there any solution to fix the error or is there any alternative package.

Comment: Install Python 2.7 and add it into Path variable. have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm

Comment: getting the following error after adding the python:Error: Command failed: C:\Python34\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];

Comment: Install python 2.7 not other versions

Answer (score 0):

This package does not have binaries for Node.js 12. See open issue https://github.com/abbr/NodeSSPI/issues/69. You can either downgrade Node.js version or try to compile binaries. See Installation instructions https://github.com/abbr/NodeSSPI#installation