# i can't install bcrypt

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

i tried several solutions. like

```
  npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

and

```
  npm install node-gyp -g
```

before trying to

```
  npm install bcrypt
```

but still it's shows this error.

```
> bcrypt@4.0.1 install C:\Users\Ethel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules                                                                                                  
\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/                                                                                                  
node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v4.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v4.0.1-napi-v3-win3                                                                                                  
2-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@4.0.1 and no                                                                                                  
de@12.15.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile wit                                                                                                  
h node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm config                                                                                                  
uration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHO                                                                                                  
N
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find P                                                                                                  
ython 2
hel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bc                                                                                                  
rypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_                                                                                                  
build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@4.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-bui                                                                                                  
ld`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@4.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely addi                                                                                                  
tional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ethel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-09                                                                                                  
T01_40_45_056Z-debug.log
```

i just had to cut the error here but it's way too long to post here. anyone knows what should i do? thank you in advance

Comment: Try to install python 2.7 and make sure PATH is set, if you are on Windows OS.

Comment: Some helpful links:
https://superuser.com/questions/1421261/node-gyp-error-on-running-npm-install

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1977

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions `python` is missing from your path. It seems the package requires python to build.

```
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
```

Type `python` in the command line and see if it starts up the python REPL. If it does not, install python, make sure it is in your path, then try to install the package again.

Comment: how can o add this to path if the file location is inside my node_module folder.

Comment: Just install Python from the official website. If you are on Windows, click the add to path option when installing. Here is the link https://www.python.org/downloads/