# Error on installing Zombie package in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

My requirements is to scrape the third party https websites by posting the details. Like clicking the button using nodejs.

I found that client side event handling can be achieved by using Zombie package in node.
I have followed the steps in https://www.npmjs.org/package/zombie

By existing the command "npm install zombie" I am getting the below error, where i could not install the Zombie package successfully.

Any suggestion on this,,,,,,,,,,

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zombie
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zombie
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eventsource
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/encoding
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/html5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eventsource
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eventsource/-/eventsource-0.0.10.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/encoding
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/encoding/-/encoding-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-0.6.2.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
.
.
.
.
.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/entities
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils
```

> ws@0.4.31 install D:\Selva\ManualNode\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

Comment: Did you find something I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this Installing the [python version 2.7.3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3#download).
Be sure you have the correct environment path.

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies) for more details.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) has more details how to set it.