# "Can't find Python executable..." - npm install hangs

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7, environment-variables

I am using "npm install" to download and compile all the dependencies of a small node.js app I have written. The "package.json" file I am using is correct and contains all the needed information.

One of the packages to be installed has "node-gyp" as a dependency, so I have previously installed the "python2" package.

Now, at a certain point I start getting error messages:

```
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:42:11
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:40:25)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:16
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.18.9-200.fc21.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /srv/visitor/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing weak@0.3.4
```

The issues seems to be that an environment variable is missing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? No matter where I search on the Internet, there is no mention of a "PYTHON" variable, only "PYTHONPATH" and others like it. What is the correct way to fix this, so that I do not get those errors?

**UPDATE 1:**

After following advice from this thread I added these commands before executing "npm install":

```
PYTHON=/usr/sbin/python2
export PYTHON
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:40:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:16
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.18.9-200.fc21.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /srv/visitor/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing weak@0.3.4
```

I find it absurd that it says "...not found: make...". Is there any possibility of it being so? If yes, how come packages install correctly?

Frankly, I do not understand a thing. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set the `PYTHON` environment variable. What ever is in that variable will be used. Doesn't matter what `PYTHONPATH` is.

Comment: @adarsh That much I can tell. Could you please elaborate? If you make an answer out of it, I shall upvote.

Comment: which OS are you using? how did you install python2? try executing it in command line first

Comment: @irqed The OS is Arch Linux. The package was installed with "pacman -S python2". Since this is a part of the creation process for a Docker container, I have no practical way of running python from the console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Python on Windows for Node.js dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: I want to thank all who pitched in to help me with my issue, and especially @adarsh.

Now the real issue was that I was missing "make" and "gcc". At first, when a compiler message suggested so, I found it absurd. But keep in mind that this is an image PULLed from the Docker registry.

I added "pacman -S --needed --noconfirm make gcc" in my Dockerfile, and the build process completes successfully.

It should go without saying, that I also needed to make the suggested changes to the environmental variables.

Comment: Where we need to add the line: pacman -S --needed --noconfirm make gcc

Answer (score 6):

Try running this

```
PYTHON=$PYTHON:/usr/bin/python
export PYTHON
```

Add this to profile file (like `~/.bash_profile` etc. depending on your shell) to make it persistent.

If your python isn't installed in `/usr/bin/python` then you can run `which python` to find out where it is installed.

Comment: Will try and report back ASAP.

Comment: It does not work. It produces this error: "/bin/sh: line 0: export: `:/usr/bin/python': not a valid identifier". Also, when running "which python", it says that no "python" can be found inside the path.

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake in the second line. Use `export PYTHON`. The $ sign shouldn't be used. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Then use `which python2` and add that path to the `PYTHON` variable instead of `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: or just create a proper symlink like distro docs suggest https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/python#Python_2

Comment: @adarsh Still getting error. I used "PYTHON=$PYTHON:/usr/sbin/python2" and "export PYTHON". Now it says: "gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable ":/usr/sbin/python2", you can set the PYTHON env variable.".

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me..

```
node-gyp --python C:\Users\username\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe build
```

We need to point to ***python.exe*** not just up to the installation folder.

Answer (score -3):

In *CMD*

*if local on drive:* `npm install express-generator`

```
#npm install express-generator -g
#express --ejs .
```

*choose yes*

```
#y
```