# unable to install ionic in windows

Tags: python, ionic-framework, npm, installation

In reference to the problem already posted in stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368205/cant-find-python-executable-npm-install-hangs), I just followed up basic installation process for ionic but got this strange error in between all of a sudden.

```
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:111:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kevin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\node_modules\\ionic-app-lib\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v7.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\meow\node_modules\redent\node_modules\indent-string\node_modules'
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\meow\node_modules\redent\node_modules\indent-string\node_modules'npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'lstat',
npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\kevin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\node_modules\\ionic-app-lib\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\meow\\node_modules\\redent\\node_modules\\indent-string\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kevin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic@1.7"
npm ERR! node v7.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

[screen shot of error captured during ionic installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBOrd.png)

I tried following steps as installation process

- installed node.js latest 7.2.1 v   - installed successfully
- npm install -g cordova             - installed successfully
- npm install -g ionic@1.7           - **failed.**

Attaching the logs captured for reference. [npm-debug.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0yadmnvfalh9vv/npm-debug.log?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you don't have `python` installed,,install [`python`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjwdflzPDQAhXEfRoKHaHHCNgQjBAIIzAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.python.org%2Fdownloads%2F&usg=AFQjCNHmio9Qjvf1yGEMWKJTaXeMN7k2WA&sig2=tCCoGZUxFJLAQeayYPSzsw) first,

if python exist set path by `set PYTHON=C:\Python27\Python.exe`,,if python is installed in default path,else changing it to where python is located.

Comment: Hi @ArduinoSentinel , I have installed latest version of python '3.5.2'. It was installed at following path : **C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32** .  I have also set the path using command **set PYTHON=C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32** still the error persists.

Comment: why was is it installed there,,the best place to put python is at the `C:\` dir

Comment: I have reinstalled python(custom). Created a folder 'Python27' under C:\ ,installed python at **C:\Python27** , this time it gave me following error: `gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Python27\Python.exe" in the PATH gyp verb check python version C:\Python27\Python.exe -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());" returned: "3.5.2\r\n"
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "C:\Python27\Python.exe" is v3.5.2, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.`

Comment: That means the `python` version is not supported it should not be less that version `2.5.0` and not greater than `v3.0.0` which means you should install the `python2` version,download it from here [Pyrhon 2.7.12_x64](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/python-2.7.12.amd64.msi) for 64bit or [Python 2.7.12_x86](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/python-2.7.12.msi) for 32bit

Comment: Issue is now resolved, I have uninstalled 3.5.2 and installed 2.7.12 into same location **C:\Python27** this time ionic is installed successfully. Thanks @Arduino