# bug:stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Developments\Python27", you can set the PYTHON env variable

Tags: java, python, node.js, angular, node-gyp

What's the matter with this bug:stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Developments\Python27", you can set the PYTHON env variable. 
My project use node-gyp to build angular env.
I have configured the python variables and the version is v2.7  ,what should I do to fix this error.
ps. I have try many methods to solve this problem but none of them work

Comment: Explai what have you done so far and how you are getting the error.

Comment: ...and is "C:\Developments\Python27" really your Python folder (check for typos like 'Development' for example)

Comment: I have install vs 2015 and launch cmd npm config set msvs_version 2015,also ,I set python env variables and I can launch cmd in windows cmd, but i can't run this project successfully

Comment: `gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Developments\Python27", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Developments\Software\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Developments\Software\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11`

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368205/cant-find-python-executable-npm-install-hangs][1] similar to this question