# Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable

Tags: node.js, polymer-1.0, node-gyp, npm-install

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /home/sudthenerd/polymer-starter-kit-1.2.1/node_modules/bufferutil > **node-gyp rebuild  gyp ERR! configure error  gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable**. gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:401:14) gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:330:11 gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:78:16) gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:82:29) gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:93:16 gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-74-generic gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd /home/sudthenerd/polymer-starter-kit-1.2.1/node_modules/bufferutil gyp ERR! node -v v5.3.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1 gyp ERR! not ok  npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1  > utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /home/sudthenerd/polymer-starter-kit-1.2.1/node_modules/utf-8-validate > node-gyp rebuild  gyp ERR! configure error  gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable. gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:401:14) gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:330:11 gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:78:16) gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:82:29) gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:93:16 gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-74-generic gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd /home/sudthenerd/polymer-starter-kit-1.2.1/node_modules/utf-8-validate gyp ERR! node -v v5.3.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1 gyp ERR! not ok  npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1

Answer (score 37):

Scott Frees' solution didn't work for me but running

`npm config set python $(which python)`

did.

Comment: For me the path was slightly different. Be sure to check `which python` to get the path before setting it with npm config.

Answer (score 8):

If you installed Python using a package manager, it should already be on your path- but if not: add it like this:

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python  (or wherever you installed python to)

Node-gyp requires 2.x and cannot use Python3 (do you have the right version installed?).

See [Running Python on Windows for Node.js dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies) for Windows to make sure you have your environment variable set.

Comment: actually i'm using ubantu 14.04

Comment: Right - the export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python is for Linux.  It sounds like Python is not on your path - wherever you installed it to needs to be added to the PATH.

Comment: Using pyenv, I needed to add this (from the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71620699/4597676):  ```export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:${PATH}"```

Answer (score 3):

I solved a similar error by upgrading the `node-sass` package to a version that is compatible with my installed Node version.

`node-sass` publishes a compatibility table that I found on their NPM page.