# Install python@2 on Mac with M1 chip

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, cassandra, apple-m1

Long story short, I want to install Apache Cassandra on a MacBook Pro with M1 chipset.

In order to install it, one must install other softwares before, one of them being python which must be updated to the latest version. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtpsOFXJUBw&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithDr.Hayes).

This is what terminal shows up when asking about python existing version:

```
> python --version 
Python 2.7.16
```

In tutorial they are updating it to 2.7.17, so I try to do the same:

```
> brew install python@2
```

and this is the output:

```
Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "python@2". Did you mean bpython, ipython, jython or cython?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
bpython             ipython             jython              cython
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install bpython
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Comment: what version of Cassandra are you installing? if 4, then it supports Python 3 out of box

Comment: Looks like the built in MacBook Pro with M1 comes with Python 2.7.18 now

Answer (score 118):

I could install 2.7.18 on M1.

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 2.7.18
```

Set the python version.

```
pyenv global 2.7.18
```

Export PATH if necessary.

```
export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:${PATH}"
```

Add if necessary.:

```
echo 'PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: ```arch -arm64 brew install pyenv```

Comment: Before be able to invoke python invoke: $ pyenv global 2.7.18

Comment: This might also be necessary: `export PATH="$(pyenv root)/versions/2.7.18/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Tip: If it doen't work, its worth checking if you have an alias for python in your `.zshrc` file. Just remove any `alias python=pytho3` and allow pyenv to take control.

Comment: for me is a yes, you got talent my friend! xD

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you will get some errors like missing something
if you are using rosetta then run:

```
arch -arm64 pyenv install 2.7.18
```

Answer (score 3):

For `asdf` version manager users, you can install the python plugin. Which wraps the pyenv.

```bash
asdf plugin add python
```

Then you can install python2 by calling

```bash
asdf install python 2.7.18

# Then you can declare the local python
asdf local python 2.7.18
```

Answer (score 1):

If you on the MacBook Pro with apple chip, `arch -x86_64` is th key

```
arch -x86_64 pyenv install 2.7.18
```