# Mac M1 python packages error after upgrade to python3

Tags: python, nativescript, homebrew, apple-m1

I am writing a project in NativeScript and I received the following error the last few days when I tried the commands: `ns run ios` or `ns doctor`.

**Couldn't retrieve installed python packages.**

**The Python 'six' package not found.**

[image]

I tried python and pip upgrade and also the command `pip install six`.
Nothing of them fixed the problem.

I believe that is not a NativeScript issue, is about the configuration of the python packages in my machine. I mention that I am using a MacBook with M1 chip and it is running the 12.5 OS version.

I will appreciate any suggestions on this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lastly, I found the solution. It was about the python folder into the path **/usr/local/bin/python**

You could check it by the following command: `where python`

In my case this folder is missing, perhaps I deleted it after the upgrade of the python3.

**That was a mistake both folders should exist on this path!**

If you type: `where python` you should receive: /usr/local/bin/python

If you type: `where python3` you should receive: /usr/local/bin/python3

In order to fix the error, I installed python again by using the `brew install pyenv`
[this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68935932/install-python2-on-mac-with-m1-chip) helps me to install it properly.

In the end, in order to eliminate all errors I installed the Python six package by using the command:
`pip install --ignore-installed six`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with the python virtual environment. Following are the steps.

1. Create a virtual environment.
2. Activate the virtual environment.
3. Run the pip install command with the virtual environment active.

Implement as follows:

- use correct version of Python when creating VENV

`python3 -m venv venv`

- activate on Unix or MacOS

`source venv/bin/activate`

- activate on Windows (cmd.exe)

`venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

- activate on Windows (PowerShell)

'venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1'

- install the required package in the virtual environment

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

`python3 -m pip install six`

Note: This works only when you are in the virtual environment.