# npm install command error in windows command prompt

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I tried to install npm in command prompt i got this below error.Can you help me to resolve it.
[image: this is the error am getting]

Comment: install python then check if you are still receiving the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python on Windows for Node.js dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies)

Comment: After installation of python am getting below error                                                                                         npm ERR! buffertools@2.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the buffertools@2.1.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the buffertools package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be a couple of things. First, make sure you have Python installed. You can do so by typing `python -V` in the command line. A version number should be returned.

If you do, then I would suggest setting your environment variables on your machine. Off the top of my head, you go into the control panel > system > advanced settings, then click environment variables (I suggest searching how to set environment variables to be sure). Then add the path to the location where you installed Python.

Here is a link that does a better job explaining than I do: [enter link description here](https://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/)

Another option would be to throw away Windows and start using Linux where "it just works".