# Unable to install "testmybot" npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/testmybot-sample-calculator) sample to demonstrate the chatbot testing using node "testmybot" package. When I execute "npm install" command I am getting error. Please find the screenshot of the same attached below. 
[image: error]
Steps that I have followed:
1. Downloaded the project from [https://github.com/codeforequity-at/testmybot-sample-calculator]
2. Extracted the project to "testmybot-sample-calculator-master" folder
3. Inside the folder executed "npm install" command
4. After installing some packages, looks like while installing botkit package it is throwing error
Please let me know if I have missed out any steps.

Answer (score 0):

To run this sample, there is now a Dockerfile included in the Github repository. The following commands should retrieve the latest files from Github, build a docker container and running the sample test cases inside.

```
$ git pull
$ docker build -t testmybot-sample-calculator .
$ docker run testmybot-sample-calculator
```

Obviously, you have to install docker first.

UPDATE:

I was able to reproduce it on a Windows workstation, user had no admin rights. Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies): you have to install the windows-build-tools package first, with a user having admin rights:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Afterwards, installation of the package in question was possible.