# Is it possible to get ffmpeg-concat running in windows?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'd like to use [ffmpeg-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-concat) running on a Windows server as a CLI.  I've tried using [nexe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe) and [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) to creat an executable but both come up with (different) errors when I try it.  This is my first foray into node.js, so apologies for noob questions.

Has anyone else managed to do this, or can point me to a Windows build somewhere?

Comment: I've received a downvote, I guess because there is some issue with the question.  What should I do to improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it running, the way it should be (i.e. just using npm).

I needed to run the following commands from powershell as administrator:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm install --global node-gyp
setx PYTHON "%USERPROFILE%\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
npm install -g ffmpeg-concat
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies#answer-39648550)