# How to set Python environment variable in Windows? or any other node package available for node impala connection?

Tags: python, node.js, windows, npm, impala

While Trying to do the setup node in windows. I needed to install one node package called *jdbc* to connect with impala. after running `npm install jdbc` giving the error  as  `Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files\Python30\", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`
Environment variable also set. But still it is giving the same error.
Could anyone please help me in resolving this error. If not, Is there any node package available to connect to impala.
[image: environment-variable]

[image: error log]
[image: upto python.exe]

Comment: PYTHON is probably the full path to the python executable, not just the directory.

Comment: besides, have you restarted your computer or at least checked that the variable is defined in the shell you're running?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre tried till executable and attached screenshot. no luck yet.
tried restarting the computer also. once i run python version , it will give the python version

Comment: Have you tried with: npm config set python "c:\Python\36\python.exe" with proper path of course...

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run Python from cmd you need the environment variable to point it to the .exe file, and after that reopen cmd window.

[image]

Comment: Tried this, But no luck. Attached screenshot in question

Comment: you're adding a _file_ to the `PATH` env. variable... doesn't work at all

Comment: @ThilakRaj it seems that [Running Python on Windows for Node.js dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies) answers this question.

Answer (score -1):

Here's possibly a solution:

Try setting python variable with:

```
npm config set python "c:\Python\27\python.exe"
```

Adjust the path of course.

(source: https://github.com/nfroidure/ttf2woff2/issues/28#issuecomment-327419138)

Comment: it looks there's some interesting info in this link, but using a link to answer a question doesn't cut it here. Paste relevant parts in the answer instead

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer.

Comment: too bad that your first version had only the link. Would have saved upvotes.