# Unable to create scss in angular 6

Tags: angular, sass

I tried creating an angular 6 project.

```
ng new contacts
```

Routing: Yes
Style sheet Format CSS

It shows error while installing SCSS, please refer to below screenshot-

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this issue because there is no python executable environment. So run this command in cmd prompt-

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

And then run this-

`npm install -g scss`

For more details refer to this-

[Running Python on Windows for Node.js dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies)

Comment: Is it supported for node 10?

Comment: ya it will support!