# I am trying to install "firebase" package through npm but it shows some python-related error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm

I am trying to install the firebase package in one local expo-managed project, But it shows the following error...

[The error message I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpHzy.png)

Please help, I have tried "expo install firebase" or "npm install firebase" but none works. I am stuck on this for days. My project just won't work without the firebase package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Python on Windows for Node.js dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies)

Comment: No, I t doesn't. but thank you.

Comment: Either Python is not installed on its path is unset. You should make sure of both of those.

Comment: Generally it is preferred if you copy/paste your error messages as text into your post, instead of linking to an image.

Answer (score 1):

Seem that you need to add(install) firebase admin SDK (which include python modules) to your project:

[Add SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk)

```
$ sudo pip install firebase-admin
```

and then initialize it with npm:

[Add Firebase SDKs and initialize Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?sdk_version=v8#add-sdks-initialize)

**Install the Firebase JavaScript SDK:**

a. If you don't already have a package.json file, create one by running the following command from the root of your JavaScript project:

```
npm init
```

b. Install the firebase npm package and save it to your package.json file by running:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

the link refer to several other configuration that you may need to double check about how to create the firebase project and its configurations.